# Generic class as argument

Tags: java, generics, comparator, anonymous-class

I have a generic class `Card` . `Rank` is interface

```
class Card<T extends Enum<T> & Rank>
```

I am trying to create two static comparators of Card.

```
public final static Comparator<Card<?>> comparatorByAttribute1 = new Comparator<Card<?>>() { 
     @Override
     public int compare(Card<?> o1, Card<?> o2) 
     { 
       ... 
     } 
};
```

How can I define that the type of o1 should be the same with o2 ?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It's not a bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the actual type in the type declaration?

```
public final static Comparator<Card<ActualType>> comparatorByAttribute1 = 
    new Comparator<Card<ActualType>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Card<ActualType> o1, Card<ActualType> o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

With...

```
public enum ActualType implements Rank {...}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the generic type `<T>`, you will need to resort to using a generic static method, because there is no way of having generic attributes in Java:

```
public final static <T extends Enum<T> & Rank> Comparator<Card<T>> 
    comparatorByAttribute1() {
    return new Comparator<Card<T>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Card<T> o1, Card<T> o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

Or, you resort to unsafe casting:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public final static <T extends Enum<T> & Rank> Comparator<Card<T>> 
    comparatorByAttribute1() {
    // Your attribute
    return (Comparator) comparatorByAttribute1;
}
```

Comment: I would like the comparator to work for every Card<T extends Enum<T> & Rank> class and only for a specific one (ActualType). I need only the restriction that the o1 and o2 have the same generic type.

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis: I see. Unfortunately, there is no such thing as generic attributes in Java. You'll have to resort to a generic static method (see the updated answer). Or you can resort to unsafe casts.